# htaccess 301 redirect - Remove query string (QSA)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been struggling with some htaccess redirects. I just spent some time reading and searching on stack and couldn't get an anwser that works with my scenario.

I'm in the process of making the 301 redirect for an old client website to a new one. The old pages has parameters query which I want to remove from the url.

`/menu.php?idCategorie=29&idDetail=172`

to

`/new-website-page/`

I have multiple queries to do, here's a couple example:

```
/menu.php?idCategorie=29&idDetail=172
/menu.php?idCategorie=29&idDetail=182
/menu.php?idCategorie=29&idDetail=184
/menu.php?idCategorie=29&idDetail=256
```

Which all link to different new pages.

Here's what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} idDetail=172
RewriteRule ^menu.php(.*) /new-page/? [R=301,L]
```

I get redirected correctly, but the URL keeps the query string:

```
http://website.com/new-page/?idCategorie=29&idDetail=172
```

I also tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^menu.php?idCategorie=29&idDetail=172$ http://website.com/new-page/? [L,R=301]
```

And this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} idDetail=172(.*)$
RewriteRule ^menu.php /new-page-name?$1 [L,R=301]
```

And it didn't work (Still have the query string at the end)

Thanks!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^menu\.php$ /new-page-name? [L,R=301]
```

Take note of trailing `?` in the end which is **used for stripping off any existing query string** in the original URI.

Answer (score 37):

In addition to anubhava's answer you can alternatively use the QSD flag from Apache 2.4.0

```
RewriteRule ^menu\.php$ /new-page-name [L,R=301,QSD]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd