# htaccess - Save query string (QSA) as ENV variable and remove it from url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Based on [htaccess 301 redirect - Remove query string (QSA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118511/htaccess-301-redirect-remove-query-string-qsa/21118575#21118575)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(hash)=([^-\/]{32})$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}? [E=HASH:%2,R=301,L]
```

In the below case ENV:HASH is not redirected.

How to store the query string content as an environment variable before removing it from the url?

Comment: An environment variable cannot be saved between two requests afaik. When you send a redirect a 301 header, the browser does a new request to the server with the new url. You could possibly store the hash in a cookie if you really want to redirect.

Comment: @Sumurai8 thanks! And is it possible to keep track on the referer after a 301 redirection?

Comment: As indicated by @Sumurai8 you can store whatever information you want in a cookie and retrieve it later. `%{HTTP_REFERER}` may get lost in redirection.

Comment: store with Header set Set-Cookie?