# Url redirection issue with redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect url using this condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/xyz/Pianos-212--0$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/xyz/Pianos-212/ [R=301,L]
```

the output i get is this

```
www.example.com/xyz/Pianos-212/?getCategory=$1&getBrand=$2
```

I need output URL to look like this

```
http://www.example.com/xyz/Pianos-212/
```

I am sure there is one line written above my condition that looks like this

```
RewriteRule ".*-([0-9]+)-.*-([0-9]+)" category.php?getCategory=$1&getBrand=$2 [L]
```

It is automatically appending query string after rewritten url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a ? to the end of your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/xyz/Pianos-212? [R=301,L]
```

See this answer for more information:

[htaccess 301 redirect - Remove query string (QSA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118511/htaccess-301-redirect-remove-query-string-qsa)

Comment: Thanks for the reaply. Do you think its SEO friendly with ? at the end of the URL?

Comment: I'm not sure if the ? will actually be included after the rewrite. You can read more here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html - search for "Modifying the Query String".