# htaccess ReWriteRule strip URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a bit of help, i'm new to using .htaccess files and i'm trying to take my currently URL (below)

*www.domain.co.uk?referrer=firstname&surname&age&email&DPECODE*

and replace it with a more concise version.

*www.domain.co.uk/*

The issue is whilst trying to find an answer it refers to use a fixed word within the url which i won't have, as it will be a different URL each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess 301 redirect - Remove query string (QSA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118511/htaccess-301-redirect-remove-query-string-qsa)