# Redirect / remove links by question mark

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to remove all links that have a question mark. These are links not indexed by Google.

I can't find a solution to this problem.

Example:

http://example-page.pl/pl?start=18 --> http://example-page.pl/pl

HTACCESS:

...

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

...

Comment: Remove them from where? Have you tried anything? Where is your code?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118511/htaccess-301-redirect-remove-query-string-qsa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RewriteCond to check if there is a query string, then using RewriteRule redirect only the first part of the url.

---

Input: http://example-page.pl/pl?start=18

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R,L]
```

Output: http://example-page.pl/pl

---

You can view this working via [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=389dcaee-8d25-52c5-92aa-26c65849faa4).

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution works perfectly :)